# Is there a way to set a specific option "readonly" in Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have the following code and I need to set option 2 checked and read only.

```
$options = array("1" => "One", "2" => "Two", "3" => "Three");

$myCheck = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('check_list');       
          $myCheck->addMultiOptions($options);  
          $myCheck->setValue(array("2"));
      //$myCheck->setAttrib('disable', array("2"));
```

In here disable is working but what i need is to set read only and I tried with following code but it seems not working.

```
$myCheck->setAttrib('readonly', array("2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

use...

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" />
```

you can check or uncheck your checkbox using...

```
$myCheck->setAttrib('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like (be sure to use "disable" and not "disabled" or "readonly" in your `setAttrib`)

```
$myCheck->setAttrib('disable', array('2'));
```

Comment: Hi Haim, thanks for the reply. I know that disable works as you mentioned what I want is to make a single checkbox or some of the checkboxes readonly as disabling it will mean that the value will not get posted the server.